Determining whether a value stored at a given memory location is a pointer

I am using the PinTool APIs to examine the values stored at specific memory locations. As shown in the attached image, I observe several unusually long values (printed in decimal) that appear to be pointers.
I used the PIN_SafeCopy API to dereference these suspected pointers, only to find that they likely represent pointers to pointers with considerable depth. Is there a more efficient method to differentiate between regular data and pointers?
You can find the relevant code snippet below:
void RecordMemRead(void* ip, void* ea) {
    unsigned long long value;
    PIN_SafeCopy(&value, ea, sizeof(unsigned long long));
    output_file << "IP: " << ip << " Read Addr: " << ea << " Value: " << value << "\n";
}

void RecordMemWrite(void* ip, void* ea) {
    unsigned long long value;
    PIN_SafeCopy(&value, ea, sizeof(unsigned long long));
    output_file << "IP: " << ip << " Write Addr: " << ea << " Value: " << value << "\n";
}

void Instruction(INS ins, VOID *v) {
    INS_InsertCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)docount, IARG_END);
    if (INS_IsMemoryRead(ins) && INS_IsStandardMemop(ins)) {
        INS_InsertPredicatedCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemRead, IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA, IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE, IARG_END);
    }
    if (INS_HasMemoryRead2(ins) && INS_IsStandardMemop(ins)) {
        INS_InsertPredicatedCall(ins, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)RecordMemWrite, IARG_INST_PTR, IARG_MEMORYREAD2_EA, IARG_MEMORYREAD_SIZE, IARG_END);
    }
}

